# Plotting GPS coordinates on a map

Tags: dictionary, gps, plot

I have a bunch (> 10000) of GPS coordinates logged, and i would like programatically visualize them on a regular basis by scattering them onto a map. Which tools should i look into for doing this?

I was thinking of cooking something up in perl + imagemagic, but projection would render it useless.

For now i have the coords stored in latlon format in an SQL, ready to be mangled into whichever format they're needed.

**Note:** I do not need the track, only the points plotted.

Comment: You have provided absolutely no context here. How are we supposed to help? Have you done any prior research? Why not?

Comment: ArcGIS?  Google Maps?  Are you trying to code something or use something off the shelf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) is easy to work with.  They offer [some suggestions](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) for dealing with large sets of markers on a map.